# Proof of implication in Product Space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X \times Y$ be a product space with $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$.

Now I have seen it stated in a proof regarding closures of subsets in this product space that

> If $(x, y) \notin \overline {A \times B} \implies x \notin \overline
>  A$ or $y \notin \overline B$, then $\overline A \times \overline B
>  \subseteq \overline{A \times B}$.

I am not clear on how if $x \notin \overline A$ or $y \notin \overline B$, then $\overline A \times \overline B \subseteq \overline{A \times B}$.

I know that in general if we have two sets, $U$ and $V$, and we have $x \notin U \implies x \notin V$ then $V \subseteq U$ but from what I can see, this can't be applied directly to the example above as we are dealing with sets in two different spaces, $X \times Y$, and $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: Should not that be $y \not\in \bar{B}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I thought of this in terms of its contrapositive. Suppose $\bar{A}\times\bar{B}$ is not a subset of $\overline{A\times B}$. There exists some $(x_0,y_0)\in \bar{A}\times\bar{B} - \overline{A\times B}$.

Now show that the contrapositive of the hypothesis is false. The contrapositive of the hypothesis is, "if $x\in\overline{A}$ and $y\in\overline{B}$, then $(x,y)\in\overline{A\times B}$." However, because $(x_0,y_0)\notin \overline{A\times B}$, having $x\in \overline{A}$ and $y\in\overline{B}$ does not imply that $(x,y)\in\overline{A\times B}$.

---

To be a little more precise, make the following assignments:

$$P(x,y) = (x,y)\notin\overline{A\times B}$$
$$Q(x,y) = x\notin A\mbox{ or }y\notin B$$
$$R = \overline{A}\times\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\times B}$$

The proposition you want to prove is:
$$\forall(x,y)\big( P(x,y)\Rightarrow Q(x,y)\big) \Rightarrow R.$$
The first implication, $P\Rightarrow Q$, is equivalent to its contrapositive
$$\forall(x,y)\big( \neg Q(x,y)\Rightarrow \neg P(x,y)\big).$$

I suggest proving the contrapositive of your proposition:
$$\neg R\Rightarrow \neg \forall(x,y)\big( \neg Q(x,y)\Rightarrow\neg P(x,y)\big)$$
i.e.
$$\neg R\Rightarrow \exists(x,y)\neg \big( \neg Q(x,y)\Rightarrow\neg P(x,y)\big).$$

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing in the second part?

Comment: @csss I have replaced the hypothesis by its contrapositive. It can be restate with a "for every $(x,y)", which negates to an "exists." The existence is provided by the negation of the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

$ (x, y) \in \overline A \times \overline B  \implies x \in \overline A $ and $ y \in  \overline B $. This negates the statement on the right of the implication $(x, y) \notin \overline {A \times B} \implies x \notin \overline A$ or $y \notin \overline B$. Then its predecessor will also be false. Which implies $(x, y) \in \overline {A \times B}$ which in turn implies that $ \overline A \times \overline B \subseteq  \overline {A \times B}$.

This is what I have essentially used. $p \implies q$ if and only if $\lnot  q \implies \lnot p $.

There are two "nested" implications in your statement. Assuming $(x, y ) \in \overline A \times \overline B$ negates the right of the first implication which renders its left also false. Hence the conclusion.

Footnote: Apologies for  the lousy terminology. I have not learnt logic formally.